# SQL Retrieve all records with distinct serialnum, between date range and count reject code = "Low Current"

Tags: sql, oracle

table name = tblName

Column Names:

```
SERIALNUM    TIMESTAMP_                 REJECT          .......
sn1         10/13/2014  7:30:00 AM      Low Current
sn1         10/14/2014  5:29:23 AM      High Current
sn1         10/14/2014  5:31:00 AM      Low Current
sn2         10/14/2014  5:33:20 AM      Low Current
sn2         10/14/2014  5:44:00 AM      Low Current
sn3         10/14/2014  5:50:00 AM      Low Current
sn3         10/15/2014  8:00:00 AM      Low Current
```

I would like to find distinct SERIALNUM from 10/14/2014 only and that have a REJECT = "Low Current"

I have been successful in finding for the date range and finding records with "Low Current".

What is not working is selecting from distinct SERIALNUM.  The below script counts after the other criteria is met.

I need it to select distinct SERIALNUM that are between the date ranges and contain the REJECT = "Low Current" and return how many it found.

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SERIALNUM) FROM tblName 
WHERE TO_DATE('10/14/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= TIMESTAMP_ AND 
TIMESTAMP_ < TO_DATE('10/14/2014 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND REJECT LIKE 'Low Current'
```

My results will give me
count = 3

I need to get
count = 2

```
sn1         10/13/2014  7:30:00 AM      Low Current   // This is outside of date range, Don't Count
sn1         10/14/2014  5:29:23 AM      High Current  // This is different REJECT code, Don't Count
sn1         10/14/2014  5:31:00 AM      Low Current   // This is 2nd time sn1 run,      Don't Count
sn2         10/14/2014  5:33:20 AM      Low Current   // This meets all criteria        Count
sn2         10/14/2014  5:44:00 AM      Low Current   // This is 2nd time sn2 run,      Don't Count
sn3         10/14/2014  5:50:00 AM      Low Current   // This meets all criteria        Count
sn4         10/15/2014  8:00:00 AM      Low Current   // This is outside of date range, Don't Count
```

I am new to SQL so exact examples and detailed explanation are very helpful.
Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SERIALNUM)
FROM tblName t1
WHERE TO_DATE('10/14/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= TIMESTAMP_ 
AND TIMESTAMP_ <  TO_DATE('10/14/2014 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND REJECT LIKE 'Low Current'
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from tblName t2 
                 where t2.SERIALNUM = t1.SERIALNUM 
                   and t2.REJECT != 'Low Current');
```

> The EXISTS keyword tests for the existence of any rows in a subquery.
>   If no rows are found, the answer is FALSE. Otherwise, the subquery
>   returns TRUE. NOT EXISTS reverses the results.
>
> The entire subquery is executed, even though EXISTS need only know
>   whether or not the subquery returns any rows—so beware using EXISTS
>   with subqueries that return large numbers of rows. It’s worth noting
>   that this sort of query is sometimes referred to as a “semijoin”. A
>   semijoin is a SELECT statement that uses the EXISTS keyword to compare
>   rows in a table with rows in another table.

```
(select 1 from tblName t2 
 where t2.SERIALNUM = t1.SERIALNUM 
   and t2.REJECT != 'Low Current')
```

This is a correlated subquery. Correlated because it depends on the parent query (condition `t2.SERIALNUM = t1.SERIALNUM`). Correlated subqueries cannot exist without parent queries.

As I understand you need to count only those SERIALNUMs which contain only 'Low Current' reject value. EXISTS helps to check this.

Alternative query:

```
SELECT sum(1) FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT REJECT) number_of_unique_rejects, 
            max(REJECT) as reject
    FROM tblName t1
    WHERE TO_DATE('10/14/2014 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= TIMESTAMP_ 
    AND TIMESTAMP_ <  TO_DATE('10/14/2014 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
    GROUP BY SERIALNUM)
WHERE number_of_unique_rejects = 1 and reject = 'Low Current';
```

Comment: This works!  I have some questions.

From tblName t1  // What does this create?  Is this a new table in database?

(select 1  // what is this selecting from?

Can you recommend a good SQL book for beginners?

I also have a problem where this is slow due to I am looping through all the possible failures, 72 of them.  
I am programming in Qt C++, is there a way to break this up to speed things up?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kevin "tblName t1" - it gives the table an alias. Aliases are useful for several reasons: 1) when you select from several tables (multiple joins) they can help to distinguish between columns from different tables; 2) they can resolve conflicts (when several tables have columns with the same name.

Comment: @Kevin "select 1 // what is this selecting from" - imagine you select from a table some columns, suppose you got 5 rows, then replace all columns with the one with the value "1" in each row. That's what select 1 from tab returns. You always can put any constant in your select list

Comment: @Kevin When I was a student I read "C.J. Date Introduction to Database Systems" and after that plunged into Oracle.

Comment: @Kevin I've added another query. But if there are a lot of different dates in your table I'd recommend you to create an index on the TIMESTAMP_ column. It should speed up your query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easier:

```
SELECT * FROM
 ( SELECT serialnum
         ,MAX(CASE reject WHEN 'Low Current' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) reject_code
     FROM tblName
    WHERE TRUNC(timestamp_) = TO_DATE('2014-10-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY serialnum
 ) t
WHERE t.reject_code= 0;
```

First it selects only the records with the right Date-Range, groups them by serialnum and assigns a reject_code of 1 to all serialnums, which have a reject value different from 'Low Current' - after that we get simply throw all rows with a reject_code of 1 away